# Weird behaviour in PDO Statement with bindParam

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having some issues with inserting rows into a table using bindParam in a prepared statement.

Here my code.

```
$table = 'companies';
$fields = array('name', 'address', 'phone');
$values = array('Company Name', 'Company address', '555-9999999'); 

$sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(', ', $fields).') VALUES ('
                   .substr(str_pad('', (count($fields) * 3), '?, '), 0, -2).')';

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($fields); $i++) {
   $statement->bindParam($i, $$fields[$i-1]);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++) {
   ${$fields[$i]} = $values[$i];
}

try {
   $result = $statement->execute();
   $this->rowCount = $result ? $statement->rowCount() : 0;
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
   $this->error = $ex;
   $result = false;
}
```

$sql becomes a string like "INSERT INTO companies (name, address, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"

After binding params to some variables and giving value to those variables, I execute the clause but nothing happens, just $result is false but no error. That is, execution of the programa does not enter the catch block.

What it wrong with the code?. Any explanation?.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've not looked at it properly yet but one thing to bear in mind is that parameters have to be passed by reference - I'm not sure `$statement->bindParam($i, $$fields[$i-1]);` is going to work ... have you tried using `bindValue` ?

Comment: Is working in another method for updating. Besides, I have some date fields and bindValue complains about "Date cannot be converted to string". Argggggh

Comment: Hmmm well, I just literally copy/pasted your code into a file on my dev box and configured the table in my `test` database... and it all worked fine.

Comment: That's it looks weird to me. ;-) Maybe the problem is in another place of my code so I'll keep track of the data just to make sure.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I finally got to sort this out. The problem, in my case, was that I had a DateTime which I tried to store directly in the database since I had a DateTime field.

The solution: convert the DateTime field into a String doing

```
$dateTimeField->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```